# Can I use my ipod touch as a wireless camera over bluetooth or wifi and watch it on my droid x?

Tags: motorola-droid-x

Just like the title says. I need something to work like a wireless spy camera.

Comment: Fun idea. Good luck making it work...

Comment: The iStuff part of this question is offtopic, voted to close.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a Ustream live video broadcasting / viewing app for Android & iOS, though this would broadcast over the internets rather than directly over bluetooth or wifi.

The Qik app might also be an option.